# How to add option fetched from the database to the end in select php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a categories table where I have different categories. I have also add Other in the category. When I'm getting the categories to populate the select I want the other option to appear at last. how can I do that?

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control <?php if (isset($errors['category'])) echo 'form-error'; ?>">
    <option value="">Select a category...</option>
    <?php while ($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo h($category['id']); ?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['category']) && h($category['id']) === $_POST['category']) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo h($category['name']); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Id of Other category is fixed, then you have to ignore it in your database query.

Let's say that the Id of that option is 1, our query will be like this:

```
select * from categories where Id <> 1
```

This query brings all categories except "other".

After that do the following:

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control <?php if (isset($errors['category'])) echo 'form-error'; ?>">
     <option value="">Select a category...</option>
     <?php while ($category = 
     mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo h($category['id']); ?>" <?php 
      if (isset($_POST['category']) && h($category['id']) === 
       $_POST['category']) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo 
       h($category['name']); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
     <option value="1">Other</option>
      </select>
```

hope it helps